# Cyrillic Characters in Ruby Shoes using edit_line element

Tags: ruby, user-interface, utf-8, shoes

I have a strange problem using shoes. I have attached a screenshot of a very simple GUI I am building for a Ruby Script that I hope to use to assist me in learning the Russian language. However I am having a strange problem with Cyrillic characters. It seems that when I try to set the text of an edit_line I just get a question mark. Here is my complete code.

```
class Verb
    attr_accessor :infinitive,:present_first_sing,:present_second_sing,:present_third_sing,:present_first_plu,:present_second_plu,:present_third_plu
    def initialize(verb_infinitive) 
        @infinitive = verb_infinitive

        case @infinitive

        when "думать"
            @present_first_sing,@present_second_sing,@present_third_sing,@present_first_plu,@present_second_plu,@present_third_plu  = "думаю","думаешь","думает","думаем","думаете","думают"
            #puts "Added Dymat"
        when "смотреть"
            @present_first_sing,@present_second_sing,@present_third_sing,@present_first_plu,@present_second_plu,@present_third_plu  = "смотрю","смотришь","смотрит","смотрим","смотрите","смотрят"
            #puts "Added Smatret"
        else    
            puts "Dunno what to do with that dude"
        end
    end

    def get_available_conjugations
        answers = Hash.new
        answers["1st-sg-pres"] = @present_first_sing
        answers["2nd-sg-pres"] = @present_second_sing
        answers["3rd-sg-pres"] = @present_third_sing
        answers["1st-pl-pres"] = @present_first_plu
        answers["2nd-pl-pres"] = @present_second_plu
        answers["3rd-pl-pres"] = @present_third_plu
        return answers;

    end
    def to_s
        return @infinitive
    end

end
```

This is my very simple verb class. Nothing Special here. 
My UI script is below

```
require "verb"


verb1 = Verb.new("думать")
verb2 = Verb.new("смотреть")

quizVerbs = Hash.new
quizVerbs[verb1.infinitive]=verb1 
quizVerbs[verb2.infinitive]=verb2
qa_hash = Hash.new

Shoes.app :width => 600, :height=> 200 do 
    stack do
        @flow1 = flow do 
            para "Subject Verb: "
            @verb_list = list_box :items => quizVerbs.keys
            @verb_list.change do |vl|
                @current_verb = vl.text
                @p1.text = @current_conjugation
            end
        end


        @flow2 = flow do
            @p1 = para "#{@current_conjugation}"
            @user_input_box = edit_line :width => 400
            @user_input_box.text = "й"
            @rwpara = para "Nothing answered yet"
        end
        @flow3 = flow do
            button("Next") do 
                @rwpara.text = ""
                @user_input_box.text.each_codepoint {|c| @rwpara.text= @rwpara.text+c}

            end
        end
        @flow4 = flow do 
            button("й") { 
                @user_input_box.text = "й"
                alert("й") 
            } 
            button("ц") { 
                @user_input_box.text = "ц"
                alert("ц") 
            }
            button("у") { alert("Good job.") }
            button("к") { alert("Good job.") }
            button("е") { alert("Good job.") }
            button("н") { alert("Good job.") }
            button("г") { alert("Good job.") }
            button("ш") { alert("Good job.") }
            button("щ") { alert("Good job.") }
            button("з") { alert("Good job.") }
            button("х") { alert("Good job.") }
            button("ъ") { alert("Good job.") }
        end
        @flow5 = flow do 
            button("ф") { alert("Good job.") }
            button("ы") { alert("Good job.") }
            button("в") { alert("Good job.") }
            button("а") { alert("Good job.") }
            button("п") { alert("Good job.") }
            button("р") { alert("Good job.") }
            button("о") { alert("Good job.") }
            button("л") { alert("Good job.") }
            button("д") { alert("Good job.") }
            button("ж") { alert("Good job.") }
            button("э") { alert("Good job.") }
            button("ё") { alert("Good job.") }
        end
        @flow6 = flow do 
            button("я") { alert("Good job.") }
            button("ч") { alert("Good job.") }
            button("с") { alert("Good job.") }
            button("м") { alert("Good job.") }
            button("и") { alert("Good job.") }
            button("т") { alert("Good job.") }
            button("ь") { alert("Good job.") }
            button("б") { alert("Good job.") }
            button("ю") { alert("Good job.") }
        end
    end
end
```

[image: russiangui]

If I click on the button with character й I can see the character in the alert box is correctly displayed. However I assign the value to the text of the edit line in the code

```
button("й") { 
 @user_input_box.text = "й"
 alert("й") 
}
```

However if you look at the gui again you can see that I am only getting a question mark to display. This is driving me nuts. What am I overlooking here?

Comment: I've just run your code on Mac in Hacketyhack and it works fine

Comment: Interesting. So what is Hackety hack? Should I use it?

Comment: Hackty hack (http://hackety.com/) is a kind of IDE for Shoes. I am not sure if using it will actually help in you problem but I wanted to be precise what I used.